# cron:run Cannot instantiate interface Magento\Framework\ShellInterface

Tags: magento2.2

I have Magento 2.2.1 installed.

I get this issue (got that issue also in 2.2) when running `php bin/magento cron:run:`

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\Framework\ShellInterface in <magento-root-dir>/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:111
Stack trace:
#0 <magento-root-dir>/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(108): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#1 <magento-root-dir>/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Magento\\Framewo...')
#2 <magento-root-dir>/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(144): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Framewo...')
#3 <magento-root-dir>/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(230): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Fa in <magento-root-dir>/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 111
```

This error is not appearing when in developer mode.

In production mode, I cleared all caches, recompiled etc.

**Php version => 7.1.**

Any help is much appreciated?

Thanks.

Comment: We have this issue as well, on a Commerce 2.2.1 site. In our case it is caused by the Wyomind_CronScheduler extension. Once we disable it, the error goes away and the Cron starts working correctly again.

Comment: ah yes, perfect. That was exactly the problem. Thanks a lot! (you should post as answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have this issue as well, on a Commerce 2.2.1 site. In our case it is caused by the Wyomind_CronScheduler extension. Once we disable it, the error goes away and the Cron starts working correctly again.